# replacement rule doesn't work

Tags: replacement

I define a function which counts the number of negative elements in a list as follows:

```
g[x1_, x2_] := Count[{x1, x2}, _?Negative]
```

Plugging in values shows that it does what it's supposed to do

```
g[1, -2]
```

returns 1

For some reason using replacement rules doesn't work as expected

```
g[x1, x2] /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> -2}
```

returns 0

---

Thanks for the answers. I am not quite clear on why Count behaves differently from any other function. If I define

```
g[x1_,x2_]:= x1+x2
```

it works just fine. Why is in the case of Count anything evaluated before it gets values in the first place? Is this a bug? I thought that using set delayed (:=) in my function definition would prevent the RHS to be evaluated?

Comment: try `g[x1, x2] /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> -2} // Trace` to see what is happening.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: and `Unevaluated[g[x1, x2]] /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> -2}` to get `1`.

Comment: `g @@ ({x1, x2} /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> -2})`

Comment: This question comes up fairly often; can anyone propose a canonical original which this should be marked as a duplicate of?

Comment: For the follow up question: Both functions will be evaluated before getting values. The difference is that  `x1+x2` will stay in its symbolic form after evaluation so the replacement can be applied after evaluation with correct result. `:=` just delays evaluation when defining the function(when you execute the cell with the definition).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `g[x1, x2]` returns `0` with your definition and this is evaluated before the substitutions are applied.
You could define

```
g2[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ] := Count[{x1, x2}, _?Negative]
```

to hold off evaluation until values has been given to `x1` and `x2`.
Then `g2[x1, x2]` just returns `g2[x1, x2]` and
`g2[x1, x2] /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> -2}` return `1` as desired.

Comment: I think `NumericQ` instead of `NumberQ` would be better. Try `g2[x1, x2] /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> -Pi}`. (+1)

Comment: I agree. Will edit.